# How can I remove menu items from "my sites" on a multi-site network?

Tags: admin-bar

I have a multi-network site, and so there's a menu in the WP Admin Bar that says "My Sites," and contains a list of the user's sites. I'd like to remove the root site from this list. I thought it'd be as easy as:

```
function my_remove_commons_link_from_my_sites() {
        global $wp_admin_bar;
        if (!is_admin() && !is_super_admin()) {
                _log("Removing this crazy business.");
                $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('blog-1');
                _log($wp_admin_bar->get_nodes());
        }

}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'my_remove_commons_link_from_my_sites', 9999 );
```

(Where `_log` is just a function I have to write stuff to the log file.) I notice that in the log file, the list of nodes is missing `blog-1`, so it looks like this function successfully removed the node. Yet it is still there in the final display. Is something else creating this menu item, after I've removed it? How can I remove this menu item?

Comment: I'm looking for this as well.  Removing dashboard access is a start, at least.

Comment: found this - hope it helps: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35087/need-help-sorting-my-sites-alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook into `'wp_before_admin_bar_render'`, not `'admin_bar_menu'`. [According to the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_before_admin_bar_render/) an action attached to this hook fires before the admin bar is rendered.